# Ruby Regex matching unexpected characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write a script that parses filename of a comicbook and tries to extract info such as Seriesname, Publication year etc.In this case, I am trying to extract publication year from the name. Consider the following name, I would need to match and get value 2003. Below is the expression I had for this.

```rb
r = %r{ (?i)(^|[,\s-_])v(\d{4})($|[,\s-_]) }
```

However this matches the number irrespective of what character I have before the v or after the number

I expect the first two to not match and the third to match.

- 010 - All Star Batman & Robin The Boy Wonder 01 - av2003
- 010 - All Star Batman & Robin The Boy Wonder 01 - v2003t
- 010 - All Star Batman & Robin The Boy Wonder 01 - v2003

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside character classes (ie. `[]`s) the `-` character has a special meaning when it's between two other characters: it creates a range starting the character before and ending at the character after.

Here, you want it literally, so you should either escape the `-` or (more idiomatically in regex) put it as the first or last character in the `[]`.

Also, btw, you have literal space characters, but no `/x` modifier, also you probably don't want to capture what's before and after the year, so the final pattern would be:

```
%r{(?i)(?:^|[,\s_-])v(\d{4})(?:$|[,\s_-])}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Moving `-` to the beginning solved the issue. The reason I had the `(?i)` modifier is because the v can be either case and not for the space characters.

Comment: Could you explain what the `(?i)` means as you intended it? It doesn't seem to be a "non-capturing group" `(?:x)`

Comment: @MartinKonecny Not sure if I got your question correctly. `(?i)` is a modifier that enables case insensitive match.  So it matches for both `V2003` and `v2003`

Answer (score 1):

@smathy answered your question (rather nicely). I want to point out that you could write your regex without a capture group:

```
 r = /
     (?:         # begin a non-capture group 
       ^|[,\s_-] # match the beginning of the string, a ws char or char in ',_-'
     )           # end the non-capture group
     v           # match v
     \K          # forget everything matched so far
     \d{4}       # match 4 digits
     (?=         # begin a positive look-ahead
       $|[,\s_-] # match the end of the string, a ws char or char in ',_-'
     )           # end positive lookahead
     /x

"010 - All Star Batman & Robin The Boy Wonder 01 - av2003"[r]
  #=> nil 
"010 - All Star Batman & Robin The Boy Wonder 01 - v2003t"[r]
  #=> nil 
"010 - All Star Batman & Robin The Boy Wonder 01 - v2003"[r]
  #=> "2003
```

- If you wish to match `v` or `V`, change the line `v` to `[vV]`.
- If you wish the regex to be case independent, change `/x` to `/ix` (in which case there is no need to replace `v` with `[vV]`).
- If you wish to ensure the publication date is (say) in the 20th or 21st century, change `\d{4}` to `[12]\d{3}`.
- You could alternatively change the non-capture group to a positive lookbehind (`(?<=^|[,\s_-])`) and delete `\K`.

Comment: That was a great suggestion. Writing the regex this way makes more sense for my script since the year is the only information I care about.